# can't resolve local domain name with bind9

Tags: server, dns

I'm in the process of replacing my Windows server by an Ubuntu server. I've been at it for a week now and i'm making significant progress. However i'm stuck on this particular issue. I have a feeling i'm missing something obvious since it looks pretty simple, but i should point out i'm a total Linux beginner, and DNS configuration isn't my strong suit either.

Anyway, here is my issue :

I have a local webserver in need on local dns resolution, so i installed bind9 and configured it as best as i could. Right now, it's resolving the FQDN of my server (**srvubuntu.domain.local**) but not the domain name (**domain.local**). I guess something (not much) is missing in my config.

here are my config files :

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "domain.local" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.domain.local";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

**/etc/bind/db.domain.local**

```
$TTL 10800
@       IN SOA srvubuntu.domain.local. root.domain.local. (
        20180202;
        3h;
        1;
        1w;
        1h);
@       IN NS   srvubuntu.domain.local.
srvubuntu       IN A 192.168.1.251
```

**/etc/bind/db.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa**

```
$TTL 10800
$ORIGIN 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
@       IN SOA srvubuntu.domain.local. root.domain.local. (
        20180202;
        3h;
        1h;
        1w;
        1h);
@       IN NS srvubuntu.domain.local.
251     IN PTR srvubuntu.domain.local.
```

Can someone point me to my mistake(s) ?

Comment: chage this `@       IN SOA srvubuntu.domain.local. root.domain.local. (` to this `@       IN SOA domain.local. root.domain.local. (`. And I can not recall for sure, but "local" might be a reserved name.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it didn't change a thing (FQDN still resolved, domain name still unresolved) Also i should point out "domain.local" is not my real domain name, i just used it as a placeholder to ask my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `/etc/bind/db.domain.local` file do this:

```
$TTL 10800
@       IN SOA domain.local. root.domain.local. (
        20180202;
        3h;
        1;
        1w;
        1h);
        IN A    192.168.1.251
@       IN NS   srvubuntu.domain.local.
srvubuntu       IN A 192.168.1.251
```

Your reverse file looks O.K., although I don't use an `$ORIGIN` line in mine.

I am doing pretty much the exact same thing as you:

```
doug@s15:~$ nslookup s15
Server:         192.168.111.1
Address:        192.168.111.1#53

Name:   s15.smythies.com
Address: 192.168.111.112

doug@s15:~$ nslookup s15.smythies.com
Server:         192.168.111.1
Address:        192.168.111.1#53

Name:   s15.smythies.com
Address: 192.168.111.112
```

See also the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns.html).

EDIT: Please note that on my LAN my client computers know to automatically append "smythies.com" to DNS requests because my DHCP server has this line in it's `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file:

```
option domain-name "smythies.com";
```

Comment: Yes, that's it ! It works now, thanks for your tips. I'm still extremely unfamiliar with DNS syntax, but now that it's working i can document myself without pressure.